# Getting "NoMethodError (undefined method `extension'..." when trying to run in production on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

HI my app works fine locally when using :file but once i'ts pushed up to heroku and using S3 I get this error when trying to upload. It looks to be a porblem with the def filename method.

The heroku logs show:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `extension' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::S3::File:0x00000006316a90>):
 app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:53:in `filename'
```

This is how I have filename defined in my uploader:

```
  def filename
       "image.#{model.image.file.extension}" if original_filename
     end
```

How can i fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
def filename
  "image.#{File.extname(original_filename).downcase}" if original_filename
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, this does work for me when on S3 for heroku, but ends up not showing the image in :file mode on local development, it just displays the text versionname_image do you know why this would be?

Comment: Different storage options use different classes to represent the file. S3 uses `CarrierWave::Storage::S3::File` and `:file` uses `CarrierWave::Storage::File`. Since they're different types of objects, they're not going to have all the same methods and behavior. This is a good example of why you should try to keep things consistent between dev and production environments.

Comment: Okay thanks again for the help, just added a if Rails.env.production? to switch between the two.